# How to evaluate $S(a)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(a-1)\ldots(a-n+1)}{n!} $ with $a=1/2$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> I would like to compute
>   $$
> S(a):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a(a-1)\ldots(a-n+1)}{n!} 
> $$
>   where $a=1/2$.

---

At some point, I arrive at

$$
S(1/2) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^nn!}(1)(3)\ldots(2n-1)
$$

Can this expression (if correct) be simplified further?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.

Comment: @PaulSundheim I don't know... it seems pretty clear the OP is asking for $S(1/2)$ to me.  They've even shown some work and their attempt at simplifications.

Comment: "To travel hopefully is a better thing than to arrive, and the true success is to labour." [Robert Louis Stevenson, 1881](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/387450.html)

Comment: Please review my edit with an eye to checking any misunderstanding or error I may have introduced unintentionally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{a(a-1)(a-2)\cdots(a-n+1)}{n!}=\binom an$$

By the binomial theorem, we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom anx^{a-n}y^n=(x+y)^a$$

Now just set $x=y=1$.

---

Note that generally,

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom any^n=(1+y)^a$$

holds for $|y|<1$, and so a discussion of convergence must be considered for the particular choice of $a$.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{1/2}n\stackrel?=\sqrt2$$

However, we may notice that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\binom{1/2}n2\sqrt\pi n^{-3/2}\right|=1$$

which may be derived by Stirling approximations. Thus, it converges by the limit comparison test and p-series, and to the claimed value of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: The formula you have given is not valid for all values of $x, y, a$ and it is better to provide details. A complete discussion of the general binomial theorem with real parameters is available in [this post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/07/the-general-binomial-theorem-part-2.html).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Good point. Its rather late, so I'll try to include the relevant information tomorrow.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Well, I hope you like my approach here. (Perhaps using Stirling approximations is overkill...)

Comment: I think convergence is not sufficient to evaluate the sum.  You need theorem of Abel to show that the same formula for sum holds at the boundary. I guess you meant the same but did not mention Abel explicitly. My +1 delivered.

Comment: Sure sure @ParamanandSingh I suppose you could also directly use Taylor's theorem + remainder to show it converges to the claimed value.